# $R\subset A\subset R[X]$, $A$ is Noetherian. Is $R$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> Let $R\subset A\subset R[X]$ be commutative rings and suppose $A$ is Noetherian. Is $R$ Noetherian?

I guess the answer is yes. Can we say from this relation that $A[X]=R[X]$? If yes, then by Hilbert Basis Theorem, $A[X]$ is Noetherian, hence $R[X]$ is Noetherian $\Longrightarrow R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: Yes, what you write is 100% correct !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add, because you seem skeptical why you can be sure $A[X]=R[X]$, that $R\subset A$ implies $R[X]\subset A[X]$, while $A\subset R[X]$ implies $A[X]\subset R[X][X]=R[X]$. So they are in fact equal

Comment: Be careful with that. The hefty point is that your $A[X]$ (i.e. the smallest subring of $R[X]$ which contains $A$ and $X$) is *not* necessarily isomorphic to the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $A$. It's noetherian because, being finitely generated as a $A$-algebra, it's a *quotient* of a polynomial ring, hence noetherian.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli could you explain the bit about the non isomorphism a little more? An example would be great.

Comment: @coldnumber I was thinking about something like $\Bbb R\subseteq \Bbb R[X^2]\subseteq \Bbb R[X]$. The ring of polynomials over $\Bbb R[X^2]$ is $\Bbb R[X^2, Y]$, while $\Bbb R[X]$ is an entire extension of $\Bbb R[X^2]$, not a purely trascendental one.